# mongodb find query getmore operation hangs

Tags: mongodb

We are running MongoDB 3.0.2 on Linux.

The "getmore" operation for a find query periodically hangs.

The operation is available currentOp(), and one item I cannot explain is that all the acquireCount values in lockStats continue to grow while the query hangs (for Global, MMAPV1Journal, Database, and Collection).

This is the operation in question, at this point running for more than 1000 secs, returned by db.currentOp() :

```
{
    "desc" : "conn60",
    "threadId" : "0x2a99ee0",
    "connectionId" : 60,
    "opid" : 67792,
    "active" : true,
    "secs_running" : 1098,
    "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(1098289543),
    "op" : "getmore",
    "ns" : "dbName.collectionName",
    "query" : {
        "d" : {
            "$gt" : ISODate("2016-03-13T18:00:00.261Z"),
            "$lt" : ISODate("2016-03-14T22:45:17.718Z")
        },
        "cc" : "US",
        "dc" : {
            "$in" : [
                "26",
                "31",
                "17",
                "29",
                "35"
            ]
        },
        "pr" : {
            "$gte" : 4
        }
    },
    "client" : "10.0.0.111:33670",
    "numYields" : 317557,
    "locks" : {

    },
    "waitingForLock" : false,
    "lockStats" : {
        "Global" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(635114)
            }
        },
        "MMAPV1Journal" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(317557)
            }
        },
        "Database" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(317557)
            }
        },
        "Collection" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "R" : NumberLong(317557)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any insights would be much appreciated ! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. So I get:

> db.version()
3.0.6

Note that currentOp.op is just:

A string that identifies the type of operation. The possible values are:
"none"
"update"
"insert"
"query"
"getmore"
"remove"
"killcursors"

This from: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/

Comment: Sorry, I think you may misunderstand: (a) I am not asking about the getMore console command, and (b) "getmore" in the currentOp.op value does not indicate that the getMore() console command was used (and it obviously was not, given this is a 3.0.6 version of the database).

Comment: That is possible yes, but prior to attempting to reproduce, I believe it will be far easier to first proceed based on the evidence provided above. That is: what does it mean that the acquireCount values in lockStats continue to grow while the query hangs, and they are of multiple lock types and modes.

Comment: Why do you say this about the output from currentOp()? Also the mongodb log file outputs data very similar to the output of currentOp().

Comment: Note It is not waiting for a lock, according to the output above. Also there were no other queries running on the database. We are using the default cursor batch size. It does not have a currentOp.lockStats.deadlockCount. It has acquired hundreds of thousands of locks: all Intent Shared locks, except the collection-level locks, which are Shared locks. This output appears to be significant -- e.g. why are there global locks at all? -- I am hoping for the help of someone who can interpret what seems to be odd output from currentOp() -- but thanks for your input !

Comment: hmm, I have deleted my comments. I think its going nowhere.